# Javascript cannot twice print to printer

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Firefox config :

dom.successive_dialog_time_limit = 0

print.always_print_silent = true

Using the javascript, put at the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
        window.print();
        window.print();
</script>
```

But it only print 1 copy, how to make it print two copies ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a "problem" of something beyond the js code. You call the printer and just after call again. Maybe if you make something like:

```
<script>
        window.print();
        console.log();
        window.print();
</script>
```

this works, because there is another thinkg between them.